# Kotlin singleton with object issue

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I am trying to do the singleton pattern with Kotlin and I'm not understanding why I am getting null pointer exception here

```
object AppController : Application() {
    private val queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)

   fun getRequestQueue(): RequestQueue {
        return queue
    }
}
```

In my main activity I am calling:

```
private val controller  = AppController
private val queue = AppController.getRequestQueue()
```

Ay help is appreciated.  Sorry.  I am not sure why code isn't formatting properly.

Comment: The code snippets you added are not visible , I can only see "..." on them, can you update your post and make sure the code is visible on the preview?

Answer (score 1):

Simply change object into class, probably android has problem to initialize it

```
class AppController : Application() {
    private val queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)

   fun getRequestQueue(): RequestQueue {
        return queue
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I want to limit instances of this, so class doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JoeBones Instance of the application is automatically created by the system if you refer to the class in the AndroidManifest, this cannot be an Object, the official document mentions how the app class is used. Please see - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#nm

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which line of code throws the exception, so I would assume it's this one:

```
private val queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
```

Although I can't see this mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application), I wouldn't expect `applicationContext` to be available before your `Application`'s `onCreate` is called, and by declaring the property in such a way you're invoking `applicationContext` during the constructor call, before `onCreate`. I'd suggest implementing the following change:

```
object AppController : Application() {
    private lateinit var queue: RequestQueue

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
    }


   fun getRequestQueue(): RequestQueue {
        return queue
    }
}
```

This should ensure `applicationContext` is initialized at the time you're accessing it.

Comment: Well, that didn't work, but your suggestion led to a solution.  I needed to pass a reference of the Context from my calling activity.  Thanks!